# How to use setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled() method if my class extends ListActivity & I also want to provide support for older version of android?

Tags: android

```
public class Xyz extends ListActivity{

    android.app.ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


}
```

above code will provide support to only API level 11 and higher.

but what about lower version I certainly can not do following:

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

As then I have to extend from ActionBarActivity but I already and I need to extends from ListActivity.

I know there is a way to get list view without extending from ListActivity.. but is that the only way? or there is another way of which I am not aware of.
Thanks!!

Comment: use getSupportActionBar() ...

Comment: but then I have to extend from ActionBarActivity. I can not extend from both ListActivity and ActionBarActivity.